# Is the “Dome of the Rock” the “Abomination of Desolation” spoken of by the prophet Daniel?

Tags: gospel-of-matthew, eschatology, prophecy, gospel-of-mark, daniel

The Abomination of Desolation spoken of in both Matthew and Mark is specifically in reference to “End Time” perspectives.  Are there any Christian teachings that the Dome of the Rock is the “Abomination of Desolation”?

Comment: Yep.  [There are Christian teachings that the Dome on the Rock is the Abomination of Desolation](http://www.bibletruth.cc/Body_AbominationofDesolation.htm).  Of course, there are alternate opinions on the matter.  Whether it actually ***is*** or not is another matter.

Comment: See also Wikipedia's article "Abomination of Desolation," where we read, "The 1 Maccabees usage of the term points to the actions of Antiochus IV Epiphanes in the mid-2nd century BC. Specifically, he set up an altar to Zeus in the Second Temple in Jerusalem [i.e., Herod's temple], and sacrificed swine on it around the year 167 BC."  Daniel's prophecy refers not only to the blasphemous Antiochus IV but also to the Antichrist, who will appear in the end times, forge an alliance with Israel, and subsequently break that alliance and force the world to worship him--the ultimate abomination.

Comment: The expression most certainly refers to the pagan idolatrous desecration of the Second Jerusalem Temple by Greeks (around 170-165 BC) and Romans (in AD 70). Whether the use of the site for monotheistic purposes by a religion very similar to that of Biblical Judaism would also be regarded as such by the author(s) of the Biblical book of Daniel seems somewhat contrived.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd limit the application "abomination of desolation" to a single event/place/thing.  Many scholars believe that the references in the book of Daniel (Dan. 9:27; 11:31; 12:11) refer to the time of Antiochus IV Ephiphanes who made an unclean sacrifice in the Jewish temple (among other terrible things) in the 2nd century BC.

However, in the New Testament (Matt. 24:15; Mk. 13:14) this would be a past event, so would be applied to something else.  If you look at the parallel passage in Luke you'll find something interesting:

> Mk. 13:14 - "So when you see the abomination of desolation spoken by
>   Daniel the prophet, standing where it ought not, then let those who
>   are in Judea flee to the mountains."
>
> Lk. 21:20-21 - "But when you see Jerusalem surrounded by armies, then
>   know that its desolation is near.  Then let those who are in Judea
>   flee to the mountains..."

And then notice Mk. 13:30:

> "Assuredly I say to you, this generation will by no means pass away
>   until all these things take place."

So if you take "generation" to mean the people living at that time, then the application here would refer to the time when Jerusalem was surrounded by armies sometime in the first century.  And in fact, we find that the Roman armies did so and destroyed the entire city and temple (70 AD).  The Romans were an abomination that made the city desolate.

Multiple applications seem to make sense because Antiochus IV Epiphanes matches so remarkably well to the descriptions in Daniel, yet Jesus' application had to be different because Antiochus was already past.  They were both abominations of desolation.

Now, as to the "Dome of the Rock" theory.  It is interesting that the Dome of the Rock only exists because the Romans destroyed the temple in 70 AD, so perhaps, in a sense an application of "abomination of desolation" could be made here.

The Scriptures in Daniel and Matthew/Mark/Luke seem to specifically point to the applications I've cited above, but certainly a Jew would view the mosque as "an" abomination of desolation due to its location.

Comment: Some would also say the Greek word for [generation](http://biblesuite.com/greek/1074.htm) in Mark 13:30 is interpreted as `race or family`, speaking of Jews. There certainly have been a few "foreshadowers" of the antichrist and its "abomination", including Nebuchadnezzar and his image, Antiochus IV Epiphanes, King Herod and the golden Roman Eagle he built at the entrance to the temple (Dan 11:31); all before Jesus spoke those words. Jesus said, as you quoted, "then let those who are in Judea flee to the mountains". The Jews were in Babylon at the time the Dome was built.

Comment: @Shredder, the Babylon deportations are dated to 597 BCE - 587 BCE, while I believe the Dome of the Rock is a 7th century landmark.

Answer (score 3):

Yes I think so. From the Jewish Tanach:-

*Dan 12:11 “And from the time the daily sacrifice was removed and the silent abomination placed, is one thousand, two hundred, and ninety"*

http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16495

The original temple of Solomon was destroyed by the Babylonians probably during 586 BC.
http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/The_Temple.html

A prophetic year contains 360 days. 
Using the well attested "day as a year" prophetic principle, we can calculate the time of the aforementioned abomination.
http://www.freewebs.com/awordfitlyspoken/isaacnewton.pdf

1290 prophetic years = 360 days x 1290 = 464,400 days

464,400 days / 365.25 days per solar year = 1,271.46 solar years.

586 BC + 1,271.46 years = AD 686

The year AD 686 marks the early construction period of the Dome of the Rock by the Umayyad Caliphate. It is also notably inscribed with words along the lines of "God has no son." Given its obvious anti-Christian message, its location on the Temple Mount, time of construction and the fact that it is a "silent abomination," it becomes, in my opinion, a very strong contender for the title of "Abomination that maketh desolate."

http://www.islamic-awareness.org/History/Islam/Inscriptions/DoTR.html
http://www.bu.edu/mzank/Michael_Zank/Jerusalem/domeoftherock.html

*Matthew 24 "15 “When ye therefore shall see the abomination of desolation, spoken of by Daniel the prophet, standing in the holy place (whoso readeth, let him understand), 16 then let them that be in Judea flee unto the mountains."*

Jesus pointed out the abomination, as prophesised by Daniel, during the "olivet discourse" as part of His warnings concerning false prophets and messiahs:-

*Matthew 24 "24 For there shall arise false christs and false prophets and shall show great signs and wonders, insomuch that, if it were possible, they shall deceive the very elect. 25 Behold, I have told you before."*

The Quran, once stripped of the early Meccan verses via the well understood Islamic practice of "abrogation" (google it) is nothing more than a war manual against Christians and Jews - and that goes a long way to explain the violent history of Islam and what you see going on today.

There's also another aspect to Daniel's 1290 days prophecy which might be of interest. If we ignore the prophetic to solar year conversion, another significant event emerges.

586 BC + 1290 years = AD 705

Using the two methods, the date range of AD 686-705 emerges. It is notable because the period frames pretty much exactly the time taken for the Caliphate to build the Dome of the Rock, The Dome of the Spirits and the Al-Aqsa Mosque. All three structures are found on the Temple Mount and from a Christian perspective, represent a foreign and therefore false god.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Aqsa_Mosque

Interestingly, a number of Daniel's other timed prophecies seem to exhibit the same date-range behaviour.

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing.  If you'd like to strengthen your answer, I'd recommend adding sources to show that this analysis doesn't merely reflect your opinion.  I hope you'll take a minute to review [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and better understand how [your answer can be supported](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).

Comment: Ok, I've modified my post - hopefully for the better :)

Comment: Extended post to include AD 705 calculation.

Answer (score 1):

In Daniel 9, the 70 weeks are 70 weeks of years, where [each day is a year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day-year_principle). The 70 weeks would not be completed until

> your people and your holy city to finish transgression, to put an end to sin, to atone for wickedness, to bring in everlasting righteousness, to seal up vision and prophecy and to anoint the Most Holy Place.
>   Daniel 9:24

and this has not happened yet. However, the first 69 weeks have

> From the time the word goes out to restore and rebuild Jerusalem until the Anointed One, the ruler, comes, there will be **seven** ‘sevens,’ and **sixty-two** ‘sevens.’ It will be rebuilt with streets and a trench, but in times of trouble. 26 After the sixty-two ‘sevens,’ the Anointed One will be put to death and will have nothing. The people of the ruler who will come will destroy the city and the sanctuary.
>   Daniel 9:25-26

When Jesus claimed to be the Messiah and was crucified, and the Romans destroyed the city.

The last week, or seven years, is understood to be the 7 years of tribulation. At the end of tribulation, Christ will come and accomplish Dan. 9:24 and put an end to the abomination and the one who set it up. The Dome of the Rock was completed around the year 691AD. Jesus says "then let those who are Judea flee to the mountains". The [Jews were in Babylon at that time](http://www.simpletoremember.com/articles/a/the_jews_of_babylon/). Jesus also says that the abomination will cause desolation, which the Dome itself does not. Given these, I would say no, the Dome of the Rock is not "the abomination of desolation".

Something to consider, in Revelation 13, we read:

> 14 Because of the signs it was given power to perform on behalf of the first beast, it deceived the inhabitants of the earth. It ordered them to set up an image in honor of the beast who was wounded by the sword and yet lived. 15 The second beast was given power to give breath to the image of the first beast, so that the image could speak and cause all who refused to worship the image to be killed.
>   Revelation 13:14-15

The image that the beast causes man to build and worship, he will give it the ability to speak and to kill those who do not worship it. Also this supposedly takes place amidst tribulation and end times, and the Jews will (currently *are*) dwelling in Israel, which they haven't since 70AD. Perhaps this "image" is it. It does not say where it will be built, but if the beast is the false messiah, it could very possibly be at the temple mount.

Comment: The Hebrew word "shamem" translated as desolation also is translated 22 times as astonished or amazed and only 3 times as destroy.  Certainly the Dome has brought astonishment.

Comment: The Hebrew word Jesus would have used would have been "shamem".

Comment: I don't study Hebrew or Greek much, but it looks like the Greek word used for Jesus' dialogue in Matthew is `ἐρημώσεως` - http://biblesuite.com/greek/2050.htm

Comment: Jesus spoke Aramaic or Hebrew and here he is in reference to Daniel.  The New Testament was recorded in Greek, however especially in this case since Daniel is quoted we know the Hebrew word is what Christ would have used.

Comment: Right. I'm saying because of the Greek word that is used in Matthew, Jesus probably meant "shamem" to be translated as such; to make desolate. http://lexiconcordance.com/hebrew/8074.html

Answer (score 0):

"From the time that the daily sacrifice is abolished and the abomination that causes desolation is set up, there will be 1,290 days. Blessed is the one who waits for and reaches the end of the 1,335 days." (Daniel 12:11-12 NIV)

**Now in Revelations we see** "She gave birth to a son, a male child, who “will rule all the nations with an iron scepter.” And her child was snatched up to God and to his throne. The woman fled into the wilderness to a place prepared for her by God, where she might be taken care of for 1,260 days." (Revelation 12:5-6 NIV).
1,260 days = 3.5 years

Now the timeline is evident. We see a chronological set of events. Jesus is born, Jesus dies and "daily sacrifice is abolished".

**Now the timeline returns to the death of Jesus then follows the Satan account (Revelation 12:7-13 NIV) leading once again to the set time** "The woman was given the two wings of a great eagle, so that she might fly to the place prepared for her in the wilderness, where she would be taken care of for a time, times and half a time, out of the serpent’s reach." (Revelation 12:14 NIV)
time, times and half a time = 3.5 years

**Now for the (Dragon / Beast) of (Revelation 12:7-13 NIV) we can clearly define as an event occurring during the life span of Mary for it states** "Then from his mouth the serpent spewed water like a river, to overtake the woman and sweep her away with the torrent. But the earth helped the woman by opening its mouth and swallowing the river that the dragon had spewed out of his mouth." (Revelation 12:15-16 NIV)

**Now the beginning of Rev 13 points evidence that the beast coming out of the sea occurs during the lifespan of the "Dragon"** "The dragon stood on the shore of the sea. And I saw a beast coming out of the sea. It had ten horns and seven heads, with ten crowns on its horns, and on each head a blasphemous name." (Revelation 13:1 NIV)

Now the timeline for the "Beast out of the Earth" mentioned in (Rev 13:11 NIV) we can see is close to the the "Beast out of the sea" mentioned in (Rev 13:1 NIV)

The Identity of this Beast out of the earth was described to use as "two horns like a lamb, but it spoke like a dragon" (Rev 13:11 NIV)

In the symbolization the horns represent Providences. Jesus being the Lamb (John 1:29). They are "like Jesus" but speaking as the "Dragon" (Satan) So the Providence of Israel and the Providence of Judah easily represent the two horns. Speaking like Jesus was the priests in the Temple, but speaking as Satan because of the evils.

Now the Beast of the sea represents that of Roman, and the Romans empowered the Priests in the Temple with their money. The Temple Priest Glorified the Roman Emperor and they started to worship the power of the roman army instead of God. The 666 using gematria means Emperor Nero (The abomination that causes desolation).

"They are also seven kings. Five have fallen, one is, the other has not yet come; but when he does come, he must remain for only a little while." (Revelation 17:10)

Now after Nero where 5 fallen Emperors Galba, Otho, Vitellius, Vespasian, and Titus. The "One Is" was Emperor Domitian the active Emperor at the time of John's Imprisonment. The one will come for a short time was Emperor Nerva leading only for 1 year and 4 months. Followed by the Eighth King Emperor Trajan. Who during his reign destroyed Babylon [a] (Revelation 18).

**Now a hint has been given to us about the “Abomination of Desolation”** "Look, your house is left to you desolate." (Matthew 23:38 NIV). At this point Jesus is using the term "house" as an analogy. "Jesus left the temple and was walking away when his disciples came up to him to call his attention to its buildings. “Do you see all these things?” he asked. “Truly I tell you, not one stone here will be left on another; every one will be thrown down." (Matthew 24:1-2 NIV) again a symbol is used to describe the fall to anger and depression in store for all of them.

You see he laid a "rock of offense" (Isaiah 8:14; 28:16) when he comes is unknown (Matthew 24:36 NIV) we should keep watch (Matthew 24:46; 25:10) Now the offense occurs when pride stands in your heart (Proverbs 16:5). By belief you will be saved (Acts 16:31). There are signs of him coming (Matthew 24:32-33). "So this is what the Sovereign LORD says: "See, I lay a stone in Zion, a tested stone, a precious cornerstone for a sure foundation; the one who relies on it will never be stricken with panic." (Isaiah 28:16). By belief you will be saved from panic. For God stand against the proud (2 Chronicles 26:16).

So No, the “Dome of the Rock” is not the “Abomination of Desolation” of (Matthew 24:15) spoken of by the prophet Daniel Pride is.

Reference
[a] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajan

Comment: You say: "I believe it is the love of Money setup in the heart of God's temple you/me".  What is your Biblical basis for such?

Comment: Your say: "Note: Carefully consider how God uses 1000 years in the old testament before coming to further conclusions later in the book."  It means 1000, what are you referring to?

Comment: I stand corrected. Rick, please read the end again.

Answer (score -1):

I am glad that least at some of the responders are reading the NT in its "context" and not seeing the gospel proclamations attributed to Jesus through 21st century lenses and interpretations.  Most biblical scholars believe that the only NT writings available at all, before the fall of Jerusalem, were the authentic letters of Paul, between 51 and 64 AD.  Peter and Paul were both gone before the destruction of the second temple.  The first Gospel, Mark, did not appear until the time of the destruction of the second temple.  The majority of the NT writings were not as widely circulated as you might think, at this point.  But, it was the beginnings of the formation of a majority gentile Christian church since Jerusalem, the original center of Christianity, was now gone.   The abomination spoken of by Jesus had to do with Rome and the second destruction of the Jewish temple.  Can you imagine the carnage and the sacrilegious treatment the Romans gave to the temple and holy of holies?  According to Josephus, there weren't enough trees to nail the Jewish rebels to after the first Jewish/Roman war had officially ended.
Anyway, that is my take on the Markian/Daniel passage.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Please see [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) to help you learn how the site works. Also see the [help] and take the [tour] to learn the site functions. I hope to see you post again soon.